Creating Permission Set with Download AppExchange Packages fails to Save: User License doesn't permit FreezeUsers permission
Given a User with

Profile Salesforce Minimum Access
License Salesforce
A Permission Set that includes the Download Appexchange Packages permission
Summer 24 org

When

Clicking Save on the Permission Set

Then

Error User License does not allow Permission FreezeUsers


If I try and uncheck Freeze users permission, SFDC auto unchecks Download Appexchange Packages permission so I'm stuck.
How to resolve?

Resolving this took a chat with SFDC Support.  Their answer was:
After the Summer24 release, all the permission sets were supposed to view/get the "Freeze Users" and 
"Monitoring Login History" attributes but unfortunately for a few instances org 
it's not reflecting.

I request you to perform the match production license for the sandbox and 
check, also please create a new permission set after performing the 
match production license and check whether you can view those permissions or not.

It has been identified as an ongoing multi-customer issue that has emerged after 
the Summer '24 release. 
It is already been identified and is being worked on by the R&D team.

Basically, I just did Setup > Company > Match Production Licenses within my Summer 24 dev - even though the PROD org was Spring 24.

Went back to the Permission Set
Checked Download Appexchange Packages
Save was successful


Thank you so much! I was receiving the exact same error deploying from one Sandbox to another today and this resolved it!

@GabeWonders - Glad this helped. I make it a practice to do a self-answered Q&A on stackexchange whenever a problem vexes me and there's no online resource that resolves the issue.  Sometimes, when searching, I find my own posts from years ago!
